# Angular 2+ .Bind each table cell to array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a  created dynamically (with *ngFor directive), each cell of which is an input field. How can I bind the input data from view to result array in typescript.
Cann't do it with an ngModel like that:

```html
  <tr *ngFor="let n of names;let i = index;">
          <td>{{n.name}}</td>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let d of n.data;let j = index; trackBy:indexTracker">        
         <td><input style="width:100%"  maxlength="3"  [(ngModel)]="names[i].data[j]"></td>
          </ng-container>
          <span matTooltip="נקה שורה" (click)="clearRow(i,n)" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
        </tr>
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: ***I have a created <table> dynamically (with *ngFor directive).

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tjzoa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). Can you post an example that reproduces your error?